# App to open in Spanish when participant clicks on Spanish Website in iOS

Tags: swift, localization, ios-universal-links

I have a project and this project support two languages English and Spanish.

If the user has Spanish languages selected phone, the app opens Spanish. The same cycle works for English also.

Second, We have a website and this website provides Spanish and English support. User can register ( Sign Up ) or login (Sign In)
from English site or Spanish site.

My question, As a User if I choose to register via the Spanish site, I should be taken to the app in Spanish and not English.

How can I do this? Universal Link or Deep Link. Is there anyone build this cycle previously?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the device's language from within an app.

A solution for your use case could be to manually handle localization in your project: instead of relying on `NSLocalizedString` you'd have to use your own function for providing the localization for a given string/key. In the "normal" usage scenario you'd use the preferred language of the system; when opening the app via a link you'd add the language as URL parameter and use that language for the app session. (Note that this will not work with Storyboard or Info.plist localizations, only with texts you explicitly set in code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not changing device language . Without changing device language I can change UI languages with one button from eng to spanish or  from spanish to eng. My question is different. User comes from web site with different language.

Comment: Ok then I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Branch iOS SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking) for deep linking so that you can ensure that a user receives the language even when they don't have the app installed before hand. In your links you should be able to set a field `language` to `english`, `epanish`, etc. When ever a user opens your application you can just pull that information out of the Branch callback like so.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // listener for Branch Deep Link data
  Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { (params, error) in
      // do stuff with deep link data (nav to page, display content, etc)
      print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
      let language = params?['language']
      //Store this in their NSUserDefaults
      let defaults = UserDefaults.standard.set(language, forKey: "language")
  }
  return true
}
```

The information in your UserDefaults will persist until the user deletes the app and reinstalls it.

```
let language = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: 'language')
```

Comment: Can not what? Use deferred deep linking?

Comment: We can not use any third party library for this project. This is project rule. We build all library what we need internal and their private pod.

Comment: Oh well then your best bet is universal linking, but you won't be able to do deferred deep linking